# Sort order "Other Calendars" in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003, calendar, sorting

If I open a Shared Calendar in Outlook, it will be added in the "Other Calendars" section. Unfortunately Outlook doesn't sort them by Name. Is there a way/hack to sort them alphabetically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 2010, you can right click on "Other Calendars" and select "Sort by name".  Not sure if it's the same in 2003.

Comment: Works on Outlook 2007

Comment: My Outlook 2003 only has a "Move up" / "Move Down" context menu, so I have to do it manually.

Comment: Sort by Name is on the "Other Calendars" grouping. Individual calendars only have Move Up / Move Down.

Comment: In Outlook for Microsoft 365 the right click option is "Arrange By Name"

Answer (score 2):

In Outlook 2010 you have both the option to "arrange by name" which sorts them alphabetically, or to move each up or down to an order as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

The calendars will take the order from how they are arranged in the calendar list in the side pane on the left. You can drag your calendar to be the top one in the list on the side pane and it should change the order of how they appear on the right.